# Why do I have to delete `bin` folder of my project before each build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a C# application which I have divided it to few projects. Recently when the solution becomes larger, I get different errors such as `MissingMethodException` or even worse, DLL not found messages.

The only solution is to delete my bin folder and build the project again.

I wonder if this is a common problem with visual studio or might be I am doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

I am working on a winforms soloution, while one project is the form and other projects are user control, data models and etc.

I do reference the needed project in other projects using the visual studio's add reference option.

**UPDATE 2**

I am suspecting when I have a new .cs file to extend a class using `partial` keyword in any projects this happens!!!! I am 99% sure, I am going to check some more times to see of this is really the case!

Comment: What kind of project are we talking about?

Comment: this isn't a solution so much as a work-around, you can use the pre-build events to delete the bin folder for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.80).aspx. It could be the build order that is messing things up.

Comment: Have you checked the configuration manager to ensure that everything gets built?

Comment: Are you referencing projects from your solution or dlls that are crated as a result of build?

Comment: if your refrencing (static refernece) the assemblies by path, do not do that. Instead go for Project wise reference. That way its always easy and flexible even if some one changes some project output path to some thing else

Comment: @Rafal please check my update. I do reference using visual studio itself I mean I reference projects in the projects that are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a common problem but messy things can happen some times on visual studio.

What I would do is to check the settings and dependencies of every project and check things like they build in the correct order, platform, output path, etc. In our case, some times when the solution travels to many developers/computer settings can alter.

Also another thing you could do would be to copy the main project to a *new* solution and add the rest of the projects. This has worked form me in a similar situation.

I hope I gave you some ideas.